# unzip an archive without overwriting existing files

Tags: python, unzip

How to unzip an archive without overwriting existing files?

The [`ZipFile.extractall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) function is extracting a ZIP file but also overwrite existing file.

So, I wrote my own function:

```py
import os
import zipfile


def unzip(src_path, dst_dir, pwd=None):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(src_path) as zf:
        members = zf.namelist()
        for member in members:
            arch_info = zf.getinfo(member)
            arch_name = arch_info.filename.replace('/', os.path.sep)
            dst_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, arch_name)
            dst_path = os.path.normpath(dst_path)
            if not os.path.exists(dst_path):
                zf.extract(arch_info, dst_dir, pwd)
```

But, a full implementation could require to re-implement the `extract` method.

Is there any way to unzip an archive ignoring the existing files? An equivalent of `unzip -n arch.zip`?

Comment: I would also like this feature!

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have a built-in option to prevent overwriting existing files when using the zipfile.ZipFile.extractall() method. To achieve this behavior, you would need to implement your own function like the one you have written.

```
 def unzip_without_overwrite(src_path, dst_dir):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(src_path, "r") as zf:
            for member in zf.infolist():
                file_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, member.filename)
                if not os.path.exists(file_path):
                    zf.extract(member, dst_dir)
```